# How to import Vuetify transitions using a-la-carte components

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuetify.js, es6-modules

I'm using a-la-carte components for Vuetify and tried to import a transition. I could make it work using the following:

```
import { transitions } from 'vuetify'

export default {
  components: {
    VSlideYTransition: transitions.$_vuetify_subcomponents.VSlideYTransition,
  },
}
```

But that doesn't feel like it's the way it was meant to be used...

Am I missing something or is this the 'proper' way to go?

Comment: uses the prop like `<v-menu transition="slide-x-transition">` as [Vuetify Guide: transition](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/motion/transitions#example-slide-ytransitions) introduces.

Comment: That's only for vuetify components that contain a `transition` prop. I guess there is no directive registered for a custom element or a like a `<div>` right?

Comment: if so, what about this way: `Vue.use(Vuetify, {
  components: {
    transitions
  }}); export default {
  components: {
    VSlideYTransition: Vue.component('v-slide-x-transition'),
  },
}`

Comment: Yes I figured it works with the `Vue.use` part. I'm using nuxt, so adding that in my vuetify plugin makes all transitions be globally defined and the `export default` part is no longer necessary on the component. Is that right?

Comment: yes, then I think your approach in the question will load the whole transition module also.

Answer (score 0):

You can import from `vuetify/lib/components/transitions`:

```js
import { VExpandTransition } from 'vuetify/lib/components/transitions'

export default {
  components: { VExpandTransition }
}
```

File screenshot:

[image]